# Food Festival PnC

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

An event organizer is planning the arrangement of 12 participating stalls for an event in a line. The 12 stalls are owned by 12 different owners and the services provided are unique. Among these stalls, 5 are in the food category, 4 are in the fashion category, 2 are in the Games category and 1 is in the miscellaneous category.

(i) Find the number of different arrangement of these stalls.

(ii) If the stalls in the “Food” category are to be separated, find the number of different
arrangements of these 12 stalls.

(iii) Due to logistical issues, all the stalls in the “Food” category have to be together and all the stalls in the “Games” category have to be together. How many different ways
can the event organiser arrange the stalls?

(iv)  Five of the 12 stall owners are selected for a survey. Find the probability that out of the five selected stall owners, four are from the “Food” category.

My Answers:

(i) $12! = 479001600$

(ii) $\binom 85\times5!\times7! = 33868800$

(iii) $7!\times5!\times2! = 1209600$

(iv) $\binom 54\ / \binom{12}{5} = 5/792 $

I am not sure if my answers are correct. Please advise if any of the answers are incorrect. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Hi, could you please use MathJax to format your equations? If you need the tutorial, please just ask me.

Comment: Please make your question something specific

Comment: Counting problems should be tagged with combinatorics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only mistake you made is in the (iv) part. Here, you forgot to select the $5^{th}$ stall.
So it should be: $$\frac{\binom54⋅\binom71}{\binom{12}5}=\frac{35}{792}$$

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I feel that parts (ii) and (iii) deserve comments.

---

Part (ii)

For Stars and Bars theory, see
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Consider the number of solutions to

$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_6 = 7 ~: ~x_2,x_3, \cdots, x_5 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}. \tag1 $$

In effect, the $(5)$ food stalls create $6$ *before/after* regions, with all but the outside regions required to be non-zero.

The equation in (1) above is transformed via 
$y_i = x_i - 1 ~: i \in \{2,3,4,5\},$ 
into the number of non-negative integer solutions to

$$\color{red}{x_1} + y_2 + \cdots + y_5 + \color{red}{x_6} = (7-4) ~:  \binom{3 + 5}{5} ~\text{solutions}.$$

Then, you apply the permutation factors for the $(5)$ food stalls and $(7)$ non-food stalls, to achieve

$$\binom{8}{5} \times 5! \times 7!.$$

---

For part (iii), the $(5)$ food stalls are fused together into one fused unit.  Similarly, the $(2)$ game stalls are fused together into one fused unit.

Therefore, you have

$$1 + 4 + 1 + 1 = 7$$

fused units to permute.

Then, you have the additional factors of the number of ways of internally permuting each of the two fused units.

So, you achieve

$$7! \times 5! \times 2!.$$